# Addind a class in zend framework 2 module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a `Facebookbp.php` in `bleupage/module/Bleupage/src/Bleupage/facebook`
I want to include it in my `controller`.

the `namespace` is `Bleupage\Facebookbp`. Class name is `Facebookbp`

on top of my controller file I added:

```
use Bleupage\Facebookbp\Facebookbp;
```

I added this to my `module.php`

```
'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
    'namespaces' => array(
       __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
       'Bleupage\Facebookbp' => __DIR__ . '/src/Bleupage/facebook',
    ),
```

It gives me

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Bleupage\Facebookbp\Facebookbp' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\bleupage\module\Bleupage\src\Bleupage\Controller\BleupageController.php on line 19

I tried a lot of other methods none of them worked. How do I accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `src/Bleupage/facebook` path but you are registering namespace for `/src/facebook`.

Also I have found that defining `PSR-4 autoload config` in `composer` and getting rid of `Zend Autoloading` entirely works better, you can then dump entire autoloading caches and gain performance. Thanks to that you also have entire configuration in one place.

**EDIT:**

I have created simple, skeleton project and added new namespace to the autoloader:

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                    'Testing\Facebookbd' => __DIR__ . '/src/Test/facebook'
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
```

it works without any problems. I'm not sure what's the problem with your implementation. It looks ok for me. Can you show exact directory tree and content of the Facebookbp class?

Comment: I haven't used Zend autoloader for a while, I'll test this in the evening instead of continuing guessing :)

Comment: I have edited the answer because comment is not enough :)